# Stop the animation of jquery on mouseleave and get back to its original

Tags: jquery

I am trying to scale to 2.5 when hovering to the div. When hovering it starts the animation and on mouse out it gets to its original one. But the problem is when you hover to the element and quickly remove the cursor from the div the whole two animation completes. Like it fully scale to 2.5 and then get back to 1. I want if I mouseout in between it's animating it should stop where it is in the position and return to scale 1. But unable to do so.

I am using [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2swqN/3/

the jquery is:

```
$(".zoomable").live({
mouseover: function() {
    console.log("hoverd");
    $(this).transition({
        //rotateY: '360deg',
        scale: 2.5,
    },2000);
},
mouseout: function() {
    console.log("hovered out");

    $(this).transition({
        //rotateY: '0deg',
        scale: 1,
    },2000);

}
});​
```

using the `stop()` also doesn't seem to work good because it flashes sometime.

Comment: `stop()` is how it's done.  `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` might work better.

Comment: I agree with @Stano. I think the whole problem is your plugin.  Works in Safari but very jumpy when used with `stop()`.  I suspect that since the plugin is using CSS3 animations that it's not going to behave as expected if you try to treat it like a regular jQuery animation.

Comment: But i just dont't get that why it is flashing on after animations. Is there any way that removes the animation. and start it again for mouse out from that position?

Comment: And the other problem in this is if it is scaling 2.5 in 2 seconds and i mouse out after 1 sec, than scaling get back to 1 from the half also taking 2 sec, which should take 1 sec only !

Comment: @Sparky672 Any alternative to stop() ?

Comment: Rather, I really think you need an alternative plugin.  As you can see the plugin has built-in options for over-riding the normal animation things you'd do in jQuery like `delay()`.  There is no plugin option for `stop()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you're not using the fallback, all that plugin does is create CSS3 transforms. You can do that yourself without the need for a plugin, or any javascript at all for that matter.

```
.zoomable {
    ...
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.zoomable:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(2.5);
    -o-transform: scale(2.5);
    transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2swqN/14/

**EDIT to address your issues with CSS transitions:**

To execute code after the animation completes, you can use the `transitionEnd` event.

```
$('.zoomable').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend', function() {
    alert('Transition Complete');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2swqN/16/

To start animation on click, use jQuery's `toggleClass()`, and put the transforms in a separate class.

```
$('.zoomable').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

.zoomable.active {
    /* css transforms here */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2swqN/17/

Comment: I know that one ! but I dynamically changing the elments inside it and also affecting other element's data. That is why i want to use jquery.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem; as I demonstrated all the plugin does is add CSS transforms & transitions, which you can do yourself. Can you update your jsFiddle to reflect why CSS transitions won't work?

Comment: It that there are function call backs after the animation completes. And for some div should start animation only on click. That is the reason.

Comment: To execute code after the animation completes, you can either use a simple `setTimeout()`, or more advanced by binding an event to `webkitTransitionEnd`. To start animation on click, use jQuery's `toggleClass()`, and put the transforms in a separate class. I've added demo's to my answer.